# Onclick in a forEach loop

Tags: javascript, html

I am not sure how to achieve what I need.
I would like to give the ability to my user that on click it will copy to clipboard a specific value.

```
 <template for:each={dataItem.bookings} for:item="bookingItem">
         <div key={bookingItem.id}  class="greenback slds-box slds-box_xx-small slds-m-around_xx-small">
               <lightning-accordion-section name={bookingItem.id} label= {bookingItem.id} >
                       <div class="slds-p-top_x-small test" onclick={copyToClipboard}>Booking Id: {bookingItem.id}</div>
                       <div class="slds-p-top_x-small">Start Date: {bookingItem.startDate}</div>
                       <div class="slds-p-top_x-small">End Date: {bookingItem.endDate}</div>
                       <div class="slds-p-top_x-small">Agent description: {bookingItem.agent.description}</div>
                       <div class="slds-p-top_x-small">Agent name: {bookingItem.agent.segmentName}</div>
                       <div class="slds-p-top_x-small">Main Guest ?: {bookingItem.isMainGuest}</div>
                       <div class="slds-p-top_x-small">State: {bookingItem.state}</div>
                      <div class="slds-p-top_x-small" onclick={redirectToWinks}><a>Link to Winks (soon available)</a></div>
                </lightning-accordion-section>
           </div>      
 </template>
```

I am having trouble to access the specific value ..

```
    copyToClipboard() {
        // Get the text field
        console.log('init');
        var copyText = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
        console.log(copyText.value);
  
        // Copy the text inside the text field
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
  
       // Alert the copied text
       alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
  }
```

}

I tried with ID and use getElementById but I get the error that I cannot use Id

Could you help me figure this out ?
thx

Edit followinf Goppal Comment:
This is now my JS:

```
handleClick2(event) {
        const recordId = event.target;
        const dataId = recordId.getAttribute("data-id");
        console.log(dataId)
        //console.log(`Button clicked for record with ID: ${recordId}`);
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(dataId)
        console.log('Past');
        // do something with the record ID
      }
```

Now I can console log the ID. but the navigator.clipboard is not working and console.log('Past') is not working as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should Use the data-id to identify that which row button was clicked.
Just see the sample code to understand.

You can learn more about data attribute from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

HTML

```
<template>
  <lightning-card title="Example Records">
    <template for:each={records} for:item="record">
      <div key={record.Id}>
        <p>{record.Name}</p>
        <lightning-button data-id={record.Id} label="Click Me" onclick={handleClick}></lightning-button>
      </div>
    </template>
  </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';

export default class ExampleComponent extends LightningElement {
  @track records = [
    { Id: '001', Name: 'Record 1' },
    { Id: '002', Name: 'Record 2' },
    { Id: '003', Name: 'Record 3' },
  ];

  handleClick(event) {
    const recordId = event.target.dataset.id;
    console.log(`Button clicked for record with ID: ${recordId}`);
    // do something with the record ID
    this.handleCopy(recordId);
  }
  handleCopy(data) {
    const el = document.createElement('textarea');
    el.value = data;
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    el.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(el);
  }
}
```

Comment: PLease see my edit .. I can console log, but it does not copy it in the clipboard ;(

Comment: add **data-id={record.Id}** attribut like below and try then
**<div data-id={record.Id} class="slds-p-top_x-small test" onclick={copyToClipboard}>Booking Id: {bookingItem.id}</div>**

Comment: The issue is not with the id .. I can print the id. the issue is with navigator.clipboard.writeText(dataId) this does not work

Comment: So you want to copy the id right?

Comment: @Ben2pop I added the code to copy the id. You can use that to copy. Let me know if you have any question.

Comment: Working GREAT ... thx you so much. I still do not understand why  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value); but all good thx